# Puting data in HashMap is taking too much time

Tags: java, hashmap

```
HashMap<String, Object> merchantDetailMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();      
            if(dataAndSize != null)
            {
                ResultList<VoltMerchantDetail>  tempMerchantList = (ResultList<VoltMerchantDetail>) dataAndSize.get("VoltDBDataList");
                vMerchantList = (List<VoltMerchantDetail>) tempMerchantList;
                for(VoltMerchantDetail vMerchant : vMerchantList){
                    HashMap<String, Object> merchantDetails = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    merchantDetails.put("toActorMsisdn", vMerchant.getToActorMsisdn());
                    merchantDetails.put("fromActorMsisdn", vMerchant.getFromActorMsisdn());
                    merchantDetails.put("customCol1", vMerchant.getCustomCol1());
                    merchantDetails.put("customCol2", vMerchant.getCustomCol2());
                    merchantDetails.put("customCol3", vMerchant.getCustomCol3());
                    merchantDetails.put("customCol4", vMerchant.getCustomCol4());
                    merchantDetails.put("customCol5", vMerchant.getCustomCol5());               
                    merchantDetailMap.put(vMerchant.getMerUsername(),merchantDetails);
                }
```

value of key (`vMerchant.getMerUsername()`)  is like `= paPzG+jjzRss4s1frqGKrA==`

Problem is some time it takes too much time (10 - 15 minutes to put elements in it) or even hangs during put.

what can be problem

Comment: How many elements?

Comment: Why down vote ? plz give reason.

Comment: Putting values into a hash map usually is very fast - provided a fast `hashCode` method. Your code snippet shows some calls that retrieve some data. Maybe these are the time consuming actions?

Comment: About 20 elements . .  It is a strange thing.I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: You should insert some loggings or debug the code to see, who is consuming the time. 20 elements should only need milliseconds.

Comment: P.S. This is not a proper usage of HashMap. You are overwriting entries in every loop and finally you will have only (7 + n) entries.

Comment: Hi Raptor . . I am putting hashMaps . . in a hashmap. .  Keys are different, so I think it should work.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you use a Java profiler to see what is taking all of the time.

To me, it is implausible that creating ~20 hashmaps with 7 entries and adding them to another hashmap is taking 10 to 15 minutes.  The real problem is more likely to be something else; for example:

- the query that is creating the `resultList` is taking a long time,
- the `resultList` has many more entries that you think, or
- the heap is very nearly full, and the GC is running repeatedly in a last ditch attempt to reclaim space.

---

For what it is worth, if you replaced the `HashMap` used to represent the merchantDetails with a simple Java class with 7 named fields and 7 getters and/or setters, then the loading process would be faster, and the loaded map would take less memory.